# Windows 10 Gradle: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: java, spring, gradle, git-bash

I was trying to run `./gradlew bootRun` in both **Git Bash** and **PowerShell**, and got this error: `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121`

The **gradlew** file is inside the project directory that cloned from git. It is a practice project from **Spring official guide**. There's also a **gradle.bat** file with these lines:

```
:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
```

I also tried to run **Eclipse EE**, which got no problem. The environment setting should be no problem.

Comment: Do you have Java installed in that folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like your JAVA_HOME variable resolves to a JRE installation directory. But as you're talking about Gradle, you're surely trying to build/compile code.

If you have a JDK installed, change JAVA_HOME variable to point to it. The folder name should typically start with "jdk". Otherwise, you have to install a Java Development Kit.

You could also try exporting the variable manually before running gradle on the command line (`SET JAVA_HOME=<path to the jdk directory>`)

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Ernest's answer, the JAVA_HOME it wants is the actual directory, not the bin folder like the path wants for javac. Took me a while to work that out

Comment: THIS was what solved it for me. I didn't realize this.

Answer (score 9):

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable location to the path to JDK instead of JRE.

If that is correctly set, check the environment variables in Edit mode.
In my case, I found that a semicolon was appended to the JAVA_HOME environment variable at the end.

To check:

1. Open the environment variables list.
2. Select the variable and click Edit.
3. Remove the semicolon and Save.

Closed the settings and checked the path in cmd using **echo %JAVA_HOME%**, and ran **gradle -v**.

It ran perfectly.

**Note**: Check the variable value by clicking the Edit button as we cannot see the semicolon instead. Windows adds a semicolon so that the same variable can be used as the path to multiple locations.

Added picture for reference:
[image: Environment variable in Edit mode]

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution I hadn't seen before in my googling.

Open up your gradlew.bat in some editor. On line 34-ish you will see this:

```
:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.
```

add this line to the error message: `echo %JAVA_EXE%`

so it looks like this

```
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo %JAVA_EXE%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.
```

Then run your gradlew.bat file.

The error should now appear again, but with the added echo of the path to JAVA_EXE. In my case it was echoing `\bin\java.exe` and NOT the full path `C:\...\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe`

to fix this, I changed

`set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe`

to

`set JAVA_EXE=C:\...\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe`

The value is now hardcoded, true, but it worked. I don't know why gradle doesn't concat the variable name into the path.

Answer (score 4):

I've found myself with the same issue, although my JAVA_HOME was set to the correct JDK path.
However Windows 10 appended a semicolon at the end of the path.
This way the JAVA_HOME variable would work anywhere but not with Gradle.
I'm posting this, because it might spare someone else the time I've been looking for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have admin rights, override the JAVA_HOME in User Environment Variable. Avoid typo by selecting the Java home folder. You must include folder before the bin ( do not include /bin) for java home.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works open the gradle.bat file in an editor and make sure that IT is correct , in my case gradle was the problem

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33086490)

Answer (score 0):

The pictorial representation of @Kyrei answer is :

```
[JAVA_HOME variable data (C:\your\java\folder\loc\\)][1]
```

And I also removed semicolon(;) from the last part which is inserted by default by windows.

**P.S:** as my reputaion is very low that's why I can't put this image in the "comment" section.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you have installed Android Studio

It ships with Java already.

Windows 10/11 access the
Select new environment variable and add the following value/path:

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
```

Also I recommend downloading gradle from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ ( https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip to be specific or more recent ) and extract it to:

```
C:\Users\{your username}\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

And then add it to your (system) path environment variable