# JAVA_HOME Variable Issues

Tags: java, java-home

I've seen the numerous other posts on here regarding JAVA_HOME variables and I have tried them all.

When I try and execute any gradle related tasks from the terminal I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java Installation.
```

If I run `WHERE java` I get `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` and `c:\jdk\bin\java.exe`, which leads me to believe there's an issue somewhere with this.

I added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191` to my path and added `JAVA_HOME` as a system variable pointing at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`.  What am I missing?  I have been banging my head against this for a while now; any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have confirmed that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191` does in fact exist and the contents are

- bin
- include
- jre
- lib
- man
- COPYRIGHT
- javafx-src.zip
- LICENSE
- README
- release
- src.zip
- THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME
- THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX

Comment: There is a quote in your path.

Comment: What is producing the error message? ..check the contents of the (java) folders...

Comment: Set `C:\jdk` into `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Comment: @AndiCover It was a typo when I copy pasted.  There is not actually a quote in my path variable.  Apologies

Comment: @Arvind That depends how Java is installed.

Comment: Also, if you're going to down vote a post; please give a reason why.  I have provided all information, described attempts to fix, and have edited my typo.

Comment: @Storms Do you need Java 8 still?? https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#x64_win-jdk

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, the project i'm working with is Java 8.  I'm using my company machine, which is why i'm dancing with config issues again.

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ or Eclipse with your Gradle? Those have their own embedded Gradle configs and JREs. Do you need to use the terminal with Gradle?

Comment: Also, Java 11 can still compile Java 8 projects. I'm doing it right now

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm running Intellij and was directed to use 191 by the project manager.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_settings_access

Comment: Do you get same errors when doing this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#

Comment: Sidenote: This is really a case where having Vagrant or Docker build environments comes in handy.

Comment: Pardon me if this is a silly question, but I can't see anywhere in this entire post where it says that folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191` actually exists on your computer. So does it? And if it does, what files and folders does it contain?

Comment: @Abra Edited question to reflect.  Excellent point

Comment: Open a command prompt window and type this command: `javac -version`.

Comment: @Abra returns: javac 1.8.0_191

Comment: Have you seen: [Gradle finds wrong JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set/44168551) And what about: [Windows 10 Gradle: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081972/windows-10-gradle-java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory) And then there is: [JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory but it is set to the right directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414769/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory-but-it-is-set-to-the-right-directory)

Comment: You could always try using the short name, i.e. `PROGRA~1` instead of `Program Files`. The command `dir /X` will display the short name.

Comment: have you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: @LionelCichero No unfortunately not

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065747/6656759? I remember once having almost the same issue and managed to fix it that way.

Answer (score 8):

Change your path variable to include `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Remove quote from your `JAVA_HOME`, it should just be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`

Comment: I made these change and am still receiving the same errors from the terminal.

Comment: @StormsEdge Did you restart the terminal after making the changes?

Comment: @cricket_007 Restarted the entire machine because overkill is underrated.

Comment: It's working well for me.

Answer (score 5):

On linux you would do:

`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"`
not
`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"`

Answer (score 3):

If you check your PATH variable you will probably find that this directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" appears before your JAVA_HOME directory.

Try changing the order, for example:

Instead of:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Make it like this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Comment: i needed to edit the system variable path to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"` (note that: you should set it to your own path)

```
set Path="%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

(very important)

finish.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was with the way `openjdk` sets `JAVA_HOME` variable.

1. Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` variable is set like this

   export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17"

// NOTICE THERE IS NO `/bin` appended

2. Then for the **PATH** variable you can append the "/bin"

   export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will define `JAVA_HOME`, if your installation was default probably the path is "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`" and then you will define Path variable with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Some tutorials tell you to config the Classpath as well, but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a maven project and while creating the project I was getting the same error.
I have installed Java in H drive. the installed files are in H:\Java.
In environment variable I did two things.
first I created a local variable
Variable name = JAVA_HOME.
Variable value = H:\Java

Second in path variable I added one more path.
%JAVA_HOME%; H:\JAVA;
and restarted the IDE again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing "\bin" from the path and saved it in a path that does NOT contain spaces.
Example:
Program Files\xx\xx is wrong
Java/download/xx is right

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can go on environment variables and browse the path of the java jdk you want to use.
the higher jdk does not seem to work properly with java environments.

here, you are using jdk 11 instead of that you can use lower version jdk like: jdk 1.8_0_201.